# Keeping track of keys in cache (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am using System.Web.Caching which entities are cached individually. For instance, if I have 1000 products, they will each have their own entry in cache.

- product_1
- product_2
- product_389
- and so on...

I understand this is a good practice, especially in my case, where caching will eventually be held on a separate caching server and every time cache is accessed, it will be serialized.

**My question is:** How can I keep track of which products I currently have in the cache? This would be needed if I: (A) want to get all products currently in cache, (B) wants to clear all product in cache, (C) want to refresh all products in cache.

Comment: At a high level, write a manager class that understands the data, and cache *that*. Other than managing threaded access when data is mutated, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it get out of date when parts of it expire?

Comment: Depending on how granular you want to get with the expiration, yes, that's a concern. You could also cache a central manager object which manages the types/keys. I guess my point is that dealing directly with the cache can be fairly limited and it often helps to add additional management to the mix.

Comment: The cache can also execute a callback when an item expires, so that can be used to sync your manager class or execute other operations.

Comment: You can also iterate over all items in the cache if I recall, so based on your key naming conventions you could probably know what you needed to add/clear/update.

Comment: You cannot iterate over cache keys. I'm concerned callbacks will not work at all/properly when using a caching server.

Comment: "Retrieves a dictionary enumerator used to iterate through the key settings and their values contained in the cache.": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.getenumerator.aspx